# Freeing CUDA memory painfully slow

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

I am allocating some float arrays (pretty large, ie 9,000,000 elements) on the GPU using `cudaMalloc((void**)&(storage->data), size * sizeof(float))`. In the end of my program, I free this memory using `cudaFree(storage->data);`.

The problem is that the first deallocation is really slow, around 10 seconds, whereas the others are nearly instantaneous.

My question is the following : what could cause this difference ? Is deallocation memory on a GPU usually that slow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out on the NVIDIA forums, it's almost certainly a problem with the way you are timing things rather than with cudaFree.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I asked on both SO and nVidia forums to make sure that someone competent will answer, and I got want I want on both ;) ! Awesome guys ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

should not be that slow, on Linux with cuda 2.2 it takes fraction of a second.
Have you tried to run host and device profilers to see exactly why a slow?
how many separate allocation do you perfor?, that does have some penalty but not so large.